# Need to delimit a column with more than one delimiter into multiple rows in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

This is my original table. I need to delimit the column segment. I have shown below what I want.

I did try later view explode but instead of string like ABC-DEF it is giving me A, B, C, -, D,... in separate rows.

```html
<table border="1">
<caption>What I Have</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Unique-Key </th>
    <th>PNR </th>
    <th>Segments </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC-12345-BLAH1234</td>
    <td>BLAH1234</td>
    <td>ABC-DEF;GHI-JKL| JKL-GHI;DEF-ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>




<table border="1">
<caption>What I want</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Unique-Key </th>
    <th>PNR </th>
    <th> New Segments </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC-12345-BLAH1234</td>
    <td>BLAH1234</td>
    <td>ABC-DEF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC-12345-BLAH1234</td>
    <td>BLAH1234</td>
    <td>GHI-JKL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC-12345-BLAH1234</td>
    <td>BLAH1234</td>
    <td>JKL-GHI</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ABC-12345-BLAH1234</td>
    <td>BLAH1234</td>
    <td>DEF-ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t as (select 'ABC-DEF;GHI-JKL| JKL-GHI;DEF-ABC' as col)

select  e.col as segments

from    t lateral view explode (split(t.col,'\\s*[;|]\\s*')) e
;
```

---

```
+----------+
| segments |
+----------+
| ABC-DEF  |
| GHI-JKL  |
| JKL-GHI  |
| DEF-ABC  |
+----------+
```

Comment: The column in Hive has two delimiters one is '|' and other is ';' . When I am applying lateral explode, I am getting A , B, C, - all in separate rows

Comment: You said there are 2 columns - col1 and col2 and that you want to generate a 3rd column - segments. If this is not what you meant you might want to edit your post and be more clear about it.

Comment: I have modified the question for more clarity. See if this helps.

Comment: It is giving me error ' Failed Parse exception error, can't recognize input near '['. Can you tell me what does this '\\s*[;|]\\s*' do?

Comment: (1) This is a tested code. (2) This splits the string by `;` and `|`, optionally surrounded by spaces, tabs etc, to array of tokens